# UpdatePanel PageRequestManager. Delay postback

Tags: asp.net, jquery, ajax, updatepanel

I am trying to add some JQuery animations before and after every postback request is made inside my UpdatePanel. What I have so far is something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_endRequest(EndRequestHandler);
        Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManager.getInstance().add_beginRequest(BeginRequestHandler);

        function EndRequestHandler(sender, args) {
            if (args.get_error() == undefined) {
                // End Request (1)
            }
        }

        function BeginRequestHandler(sender, args) {
            // Start Request (2)
        }

        $('.MyButtons').live('click', function () {
            // Before request (3)
        });
    });
</script>

<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server">
   <ContentTemplate>
      <asp:Button runat="server" CssClass="MyButtons"/>
   </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Let say I want to put some animation code at (3) that will be executed and then proceed with `BeginRequestHandler` function. How should I do that? Because right now the whole process executes 3,2,1 and I dn't know how to add that delay between steps 3 and 2. In other words I want to execute step 2 manually at step 3. Don't really want to use hidden buttons to do that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I ended up using the following:

```
$('.MyButtons').live('click', function () {
    var element = this;
    $('#hideMe').hide('slow', function () {
        __doPostBack(element.id.replace(/_/g, '$'), ''); // This will trigger a postback on a clicked server control
    });
    return false; // This will prevent asp.net click event on the server control
}
```